# Can I use an interface as a parameter when writing a function which could end up being passed any kind of struct?

Tags: go, struct, interface

I am trying to write a function which could end up taking any kind of struct... let's say it is like this :

```
func setDate(s timestamp, data interface{}){
    data.Date = timestamp
}
```

I realize that I wouldn't need a function to set this value in real life, I am trying to learn more about how interfaces work, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could approach it that way, but then inside `setDate()` you would need to use reflection to set the `Date` field. Go is a statically typed language, so if the (static) type of `data` is `interface{}` (which says nothing about it), you can't really do anything useful with it (you can't refer to its `Date` field, because there is no guarantee that its value has a `Date` field).

Instead you should define a `HasDate` interface which contains a single method:

```
type HasDate interface {
    SetDate(s time.Time)
}
```

The ability to set the date. And your function should expect a value of this interface type:

```
func setDate(s time.Time, data HasDate) {
    data.SetDate(s)
}
```

Anyone who implements this `HasDate` interface can be passed to your `setDate()` function. Note that in Go implementing interfaces is implicit: there is no declaration of intent. This means any type that has a `SetDate(time.Time)` method implements this `HasDate` interface without even knowing this interface exists.

This is an example type that implements it (more precisely its pointer `*MyType`):

```
type MyType struct {
    date time.Time
}

func (mt *MyType) SetDate(s time.Time) {
    mt.date = s
}
```

Example testing it (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3eMElK1Tolz)):

```
mt := &MyType{}

setDate(time.Now(), mt)

fmt.Println(mt.date)
```